# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not Int

Tags: swift

```
if let hrAverage: Int = (oldHR1+oldHR2+oldHR3+oldHR4+heartRate!)/5 {
    print(hrAverage)
} else {
     let hrAverage = (oldHR1+oldHR2+oldHR3+oldHR4) / 4
     print(hrAverage)
}
```

Getting this error saying:

> "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not Int"

I've been stuck on how to get rid of it. I have to unwrap value `heartRate` using optional binding.

Comment: Numbered variable names like `oldHR1`, `oldHR2`, etc. are a very good indication that you should be using an array.

Answer (score 1):

Don't force-unwrap what you are using conditional binding to unwrap:

```
if let hr = heartRate {
    let hrAverage: Int = (oldHR1 + oldHR2 + oldHR3 + oldHR4 + hr) / 5
    print(hrAverage)
} else {
    let hrAverage = (oldHR1 + oldHR2 + oldHR3 + oldHR4) / 4
    print(hrAverage)
}
```

If you need `hrAverage` in the rest of your code here is a neater approach:

```
let compactArray = [oldHR1, oldHR2, oldHR3, oldHR4] + [heartRate].compactMap{$0}
let hrAverage: Int = compactArray.reduce(0, +)/compactArray.count
```

Comment: There you go, that's a much better answer - better than mine!

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I still think there is a better way. I'll remove the extraneous comments shortly

Comment: Does a function exist that combines both `.compactMap()` *and* `.reduce()`?

Comment: You're kind of cheating there, ha. But you could also do `+ heartRate == nil ? [] : [heartRate]` instead of `+ [heartRate].compactMap`. That seems more readable in the context of checking for nil

Comment: Readability is subjective, but I can understand your point. `compactArray` could have been a `var` and conditionally append `heartRate`to it, that would also be readable. Coding styles are personal preference at the end of the day. But performance is a neutral gauge: The `compactMap` applied on `[heartRate]` alone removes any unnecessary compact mapping on `oldHR1`, `oldHR2`, `oldHR3`, `oldHR4`. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

`(oldHR1+oldHR2+oldHR3+oldHR4+heartRate!)/5` does not produce an optional which is required to use the `if let` statement.

I suggest you do the following:

```
let average = {
    if let rate = heartRate {
        return (oldHR1 + oldHR2 + oldHR3 + oldHR4 + rate) / 5
    } else {
        return (oldHR1 + oldHR2 + oldHR3 + oldHR4) / 4
    }    
}()
```

Now you have a variable that you can use outside your `if` statement. If you don't need that, you can stick with the following solution:

```
if let rate = heartRate {
    let average = (oldHR1 + oldHR2 + oldHR3 + oldHR4 + rate) / 5
} else {
    let average = (oldHR1 + oldHR2 + oldHR3 + oldHR4) / 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbered variable names like `oldHR1`, `oldHR2`, etc. are a *very* good indication that you should be using an array. In this case, I would recommend you extract this running-average calculation into its own data types, that makes it nice and easy to handle this data.

```
struct RunningAverage {
    let maxSize: Int
    var samples: [Double]

    init(maxSize: Int, initialSamples samples: [Double] = []) {
        self.maxSize = maxSize
        self.samples = samples
    }

    mutating func addSample(_ newValue: Double) {
        samples.append(newValue)
        if maxSize < samples.count { samples.removeFirst() }
    }

    /// Will return `nil` when there are no samples.
    /// This allows for easy nil coalescence, without introducing the full burden of
    /// needing to unwrap in the case when the samples are known to be non-empty.
    var average: Double! {
        if self.samples.isEmpty { return nil }
        return samples.reduce(0, +) / Double(samples.count)
    }
}

var runningAverage = RunningAverage(maxSize: 5)
let mockSamples = 1...10
let runningAverages = mockSamples.map { mockSample -> Double in 
    runningAverage.addSample(Double(mockSample))
    return runningAverage.average
}
print(runningAverages) // => [1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
```

Comment: Why make `average` an IUO? If you're returning `nil`, make it optional, otherwise just make it a regular variable - you could just return `0` for instance. It'll make the application crash, even though the variable implicitly says it won't be nil

Comment: @LinusGeffarth 1) `0` is not a universally sensible default. If I'm making an app to automatically alert emergency services when a heart rate drops below some threshold, say 30 bpm, then assuming that "the average of no heart rates is a heart rate of 0" would cause a false alarm. The utility of an optional is that it allows for the caller to easily decide how to handle the `nil` case, rather than having `0` be imposed by the library author. If the caller really does want `nil` to be `0`, they can do `.average ?? 0`, easy.

Comment: Get your point, accepted. But still, why `Double!` instead of `Double?`

Comment: @LinusGeffarth 2) But, the benefit of easy nil coalescence comes at a high syntactic cost. `nil` would only possible for the first little while of this objects life time. After the average values become non-nil, they'll never go back to `nil` again. Forcing safe unwraps throughout the code doesn't make sense, if it's known that no further nils are possible. For example, OP might have a sampling UI that indicates to the user that the heart rate is being sampled, without showing the heart rate until enough samples can be taken.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth After this "Measuring heart-rate, please wait" UI is done, and enough samples are available, the running average will be non-nil, and will continue to be non-nil for the rest of the lifetime of the object. It's entirely possible that the `average` function is never called before this point.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth This is pretty much what returning a IUO always means. It doesn't "implicitly say the variable won't be nil". Non optionals say that, explicitly. It says "this variable will be non-nil in some cases that the type system is not sufficiently advanced to express, so there's an informal, compile unenforced contract that's laid out in this function's documentation"

Comment: When knowing *for sure* that it cannot be nil, then yes, go ahead and make it an IUO. I think it's bad practice to allow the app to crash, even in the unlikeliest scenario. In the end, it doesn't make a difference for how long it *could* crash, because if it crashes when launching the app for the first time - which would be the only time it could crash b/c there's no data, like you mentioned - the user will deinstall it immediately, because it cannot be used at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182284/discussion-between-alexander-and-linusgeffarth).

Comment: I've never understood why we even have IUOs. 1) they allow your app to crash even though you don't expect it to and 2) it's simply confusing.